# how to get file size or object size in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have an table contain three columns ID,Obj_name,Object in a table. Object refers to metadata/File which is located in folder. How can write a script to check what is the file size of each object.

Output like

ID,Obj_name,Object,File_size.

let me know if there is any idea.

Comment: What does "located in folder" mean?  Are you saying that the `object` column is a `bfile`?  A path to a file on the database server operating system?  A path for which an Oracle `directory` object has been created (and that you have been given permission on)?  A path on a different file system?

Comment: yes, object is an bfile and path to a file is on DB operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
 DECLARE
 v_fexists      BOOLEAN;
 v_file_length  NUMBER;
 v_block_size   BINARY_INTEGER;
 BEGIN
  UTL_FILE.FGETATTR
     ('NFS_DIR', 'west.txt', v_fexists, v_file_length, 

 v_block_size);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_file_length);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `object` is a `bfile`, you can do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION( p_id IN INTEGER )
  RETURN INTEGER
IS
  l_bfile  bfile;
  l_length integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT object
    INTO l_bfile
    FROM your_table
   WHERE id = p_id;

  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  /* Get the length of the LOB: */
  l_length := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_bfile);
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(l_bfile);

  RETURN l_length;
END;
```

and then call that function from your query passing in the `id`.  Note that this example is taken directly from the [documentation on LOBs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96591/adl12bfl.htm#873011)

Comment: ID Object+path object
1 c:/users/ text.txt
2 c:/users/ text1.txt
3 c:/users/ text2.txt
4 c:/users/ text3.txt

Comment: ID Object+path object
1 c:/users/ text.txt
2 c:/users/ text1.txt
3 c:/users/ text2.txt
4 c:/users/ text3.txt

Comment: @user3280677 - OK.  So then `object` is not a `bfile` like you originally said?  It's a `varchar2`?  Is this a path to a file on the database server?  Is there an Oracle directory object for `c:\users`?  Do you have read access on that Oracle directory object?

Comment: Sorry i missed it.Path i have given temporary. we do have read access to that object.

Comment: @user3280677 - Not sure I follow.  What do you mean that the path is temporary?  What is the name of the Oracle directory object (that appears in all_directories) that points to `c:\users` on the database server file system?

Comment: path is /u01/oradata/

Comment: @user3280677 - What is the name of the Oracle directory object (that appears in all_directories) that points to `/u01/oradata` (which is a terrible place, incidentally, to put data files that are not Oracle data files).

Comment: Yes, you are right.. i have give sample path where files will be located. its not same path mentioned above. path for all files with be the same. only file name will be different. for that path we have all access.

Comment: What is the name of the Oracle directory object (the result of a `create directory` statement, an object that appears in `all_directories`) that points to the operating system directory where the files are located?

Comment: exact directory name is NFS_DIR

Comment: Hi Justin, finally able to get the out put.DECLARE
    v_fexists      BOOLEAN;
     v_file_length  NUMBER;
    v_block_size   BINARY_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
   UTL_FILE.FGETATTR
         ('NFS_DIR', 'west.txt', v_fexists, v_file_length, 

v_block_size);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_file_length);
    END;